# Javascript how to check if a condition is already met and not apply it again?

Tags: javascript

Trying not set the background color every time the count is 7 or less, if its already red it shouldnt set it again.

```
<div class="parent">
    <ul class="list">
        <li class="item">Item 1</li>
        <li class="item">Item 2</li>
        <li class="item">Item 3</li>
        <li class="item">Item 4</li>
        <li class="item">Item 5</li>
        <li class="item">Item 6</li>
        <li class="item">Item 7</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How can I stop setting the color over and over once the count is less than 7?

```
var parent = document.querySelector('.parent');


parent.addEventListener('click', changeColor, false);

function changeColor( e ) {
    var element = e.target;
    var item = document.querySelectorAll('.item'); 

    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);

    if( item.length <= 7 ) {

        parent.style.background = "red";
        console.log(

        item.length + " set backgroud color"
        )

    }


    }
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/Grundizer/awc6rymn/

Comment: I have updated your fiddle, does this work? http://jsfiddle.net/awc6rymn/3/

Comment: Why is it a problem if you set it to red when it's already red?

Comment: Im using red as an example, it could be an image and setting it multiple times can choke the browser.

Comment: You can also work with CSS classes in that case

Comment: Did you check my answer / fiddle? If this solves the question, please accept it

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this should do the trick:

```
var parent = document.querySelector('.parent');
var background = 'false';

parent.addEventListener('click', changeColor, false);

function changeColor( e ) {
    var element = e.target;
    var item = document.querySelectorAll('.item'); 

    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);

    if( item.length <= 7 && parent.style.background != 'red') {

        parent.style.background = "red";
        console.log(

        item.length + " set backgroud color"
        )

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could remove event listener if count is under 7. That way, not only you're not changing color again, you're not running anything on click anymore.

```
if( item.length <= 7 ) {

        parent.style.background = "red";
        parent.removeEventListener('click', changeColor, false);

    }
```

And if somewhere you have a function adding element, simply start listening again.